# Select a document from a Sharepoint Document libary and download it

Tags: web-services, custom-actions, download

Task: The user selects a document and then presses a custom action that sends the document with metadata to an external jaxrs webservice that saves this document to a database.

Is there any custom code in c# i can use to complete this task ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

0) Create Custom Action - 
http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/custom-actions-in-sharepoint-2013.html

1) Download file: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom

2) Upload file: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478985.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom action to call an application page (ASPX).You have instructions in this [link](https://jasear.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/sharepoint-2010-custom-action-that-executes-custom-code/).

In this page, you can put code to download the file. Something like this:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
if (Request.QueryString["file"] != null)
    DescargarDocumento(Request.QueryString["file"].ToString());
}

private void DescargarDocumento (string fileName) {

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {

    using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url)) {
        using (SPWeb mi_web = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb()) {

            string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath( fileName ); 
            string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName( path );
            Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile spFile = mi_web.GetFile(fileName);

            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();

            Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
            Response.AppendHeader( "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name );
            Response.BinaryWrite(spFile.OpenBinary()); 
            Response.End(); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```